# Reducing $ \langle a,b \vert ab^{-1}ab^{-1}=1 \rangle $ into more useful form.

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

I am working on a question and have found the group presentation in the form of $$ \langle a,b \vert ab^{-1}ab^{-1}=1 \rangle $$

I believe I need to reduce this further but am unsure how. I've tried to manipulate the relator to see where that leads me but I haven't managed anything useful so far.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Rewrite using $x=ab^{-1}, y=a$.

Comment: If you change generators to $x=ab^{-1}$, $y=a$, then the presentation becomes $\langle x,y \mid x^2 \rangle$, which is a free product $C_2 * {\mathbb Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=ab^{-1}$. Then $bx=a$, so the presentation becomes

$$\begin{align}
\langle a, b, x\mid x^2, bx=a\rangle &\cong\langle b,x\mid x^2\rangle \\
&\cong\langle b\mid\rangle\ast\langle x\mid x^2\rangle \\
&\cong\Bbb Z\ast\Bbb Z_2.
\end{align}$$